# Probably false type-warning when calling min on enumerate with key function

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, warnings

I have what I think is a false warning for the following (simplified) code:

```
import random

def by_value(tup: Tuple[int, int]):
    _, val = tup
    return val

random_ints: List[int] = random.sample(range(100), 100)
index, value = min(enumerate(random_ints), key=by_value)
```

IntelliJ is giving me the following warning:

> Unexpected type(s):`(enumerate[int], (tup: Tuple[int, int]) -> int)`
> Possible type(s):  `(Iterable[int], (int) -> Any)` `(Iterable[int], None)`

Am I correct in this being an error in the code analysis? If so how can I get rid of the warning? (If not how do I correct the code).

Comment: Yeah. it seems you are correct. But typing is never 100% precise. Either for bugs/special cases. Or just it is too complex or not useful to generalize too much (if we have just `Any`, we lose most error checkings. On context menu you can disable introspection for that specific line.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi are there any type hints I could add to dismiss this warning?

Comment: I would just disable type checking on such line (there is a directive, the context menu add it). Else you can define a `min_tuple`, with your types, and it just call `min` (amybe still disabling warning, but only on one place). The type hints gives also just `int` (and not `float`), so there may be other cases we do not see in PyCharm. Maybe it is just enumarate vs iter, or I do not know. I never add my typing, because it is very unstable between one version and the next.